# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$?

I tried using ratio test and root test , applying the latter leaves me with the same type of problem again that is with  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{(n-1)!}$ ?.

Comment: Hint: If $|z|<1$ then $|z^{n!}|<|z^n|$. If $|z|\geq1$ then $|z^{n!}|\geq1$.

Comment: While the ratio test and root test are important tools, @YuxiaoXie gives a simple, straightforward argument which is very useful for understanding the series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check that ratio test:

$$\left|\frac{z^{(n+1)!}}{z^{n!}}\right|=|z^{(n+1)!-n!}|=|z^{n(n!)}|$$

Let $n(n!)=k$ so that we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{z^{(n+1)!}}{z^{n!}}\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty}|z^k|$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yup..ok..through ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you misunderstood the root test. 
You say you get a sum when applying it, but you shouldn't get that.

We have $a_n=z^{n!}$. Therefore $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = \sqrt[n]{|z^{n!}|} = |z^{(n-1)!}|$.

Now, the root test states that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} <1$, the series converges, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} >1$ the series diverges. So you want to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z^{(n-1)!}|$. For which $z$ is this larger than one and for which $z$ is this smaller than one?

Comment: for $|z| < 1$ the series should converge right and for $|z|>1$ the series should diverge

Comment: @BAYMAX Yup, that's the radius of convergence.

Comment: @BAYMAX Yes. You are missing one case, and that is $|z|=1$. This can't be handled by the root test or the ratio test, but should be straightforward.

Comment: If I may check up with you, it diverges for all $|z|=1$, right?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, because $z=e^{i\theta}$. If $\theta = \frac{p}{q}$, then $z^{n!}=e^{i\theta n!} = 1$ for large enough $n$. If $\theta$ isn't rational, it follows by continuity.

Answer (score 1):

*Hadamard's formula* gives the answer at once:

If $\sum_n a_n zn$ is a power series, its radius of convergence $R$ is given by
$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \bigl(\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}\bigr)=1.$$