# find the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

find the radius  of convergence  of the power series  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!}$.

My attempt : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$ is a power series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {c_n z^n}$ with
$$
c_n=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n=k!$ for some integer $k$,}\\
0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

Any hints/idea/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/491088/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2130255/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/595501/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20z%5E%7Bn!%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: thnaks u @MartinR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series is $\sum_k a_kz^k$ where $a_1=2$,  $a_k=1$ if $k=n!$ for some $n\ge2$,  and $a_k=0$ otherwise.

Comment: if  $k =1 $ how  $ a_1 = 2 ?$  can u elaborate more

Comment: @jasmine : because $0!=1!=1$

Comment: @Ayoub thanks  i missed that  logics

Answer (score 4):

The radius has to be 1.  If $\vert z \vert \ge 1$, then the series can't converge because its terms don't approach $0$.  If $\vert z \vert \lt 1$, then the series is smaller in absolute value than $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^n}$, which converges to $1/(1-z)$ when $\vert z \vert \lt 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem ($r=\frac1{\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mid a_n\mid^{\frac1n}}$) and the fact that $\begin{cases}a_k=1, k=n!\\a_k=0,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  You'll get $r=1$.

Or Abel's test, to get $r\ge1$.  Then $r\le1$ since $a_n\not\to0$.